# Canon printer ink level detection

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 printing to my Canon MG6250 printer worked out of the box. However automatic paper switching did not.

After unsuccessfully asking for help on the Gutenprint forum I downloaded and installed the official Canon Linux driver. Automatic paper detection now works and the quality of colour printing to plain paper is much better. However the ink levels are not reported. Instead I get "Marker levels are not reported for this printer".

CUPS reports the ink levels on the other printer queue **which is the same printer** even though I have de-installed the Gutenprint driver.

If I try `cngpijmonmg6200 MG6200` a Canon Status Monitor Window appears saying "No such printer".

Between the two queue entries I have all the parts of a fully working printer driver, but I cant work out how to assemble them into a single queue. Any ideas?

Here is my printers.conf file

[image: printers.conf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time investigating this and the answer was remarkably simple.

1. Remove the gutenprint driver `sudo apt-get remove gimp-gutenprint gutenprint-doc libgutenprint-doc` `sudo apt-get autoremove`
2. Remove the printer queue that used the gutenprint driver. I used the printers GUI. Start by typing printers into the dash